# FireFox AddOn SDK close current tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am porting a Chrome Extension for FireFox using the Add-On SDK. I am using `require("sdk/page-mod")` to run a content script at the start of the document.

In the code, I need to close the current tab if some condition is met. In Chrome, I can send a message to the *background.js* file to have it close the current tab, but I am not able to figure this out for Firefox.

`window.close()` is very unreliable and I need to figure out a way to call a function in the *main.js* file from my content script.

Appreciate your help.

EDIT:
Below is my Chrome code, I need to port the same to FF AddOn SDK (FF Extension).

```
//in the content.js file
function closeCurrTab() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "closeTab"}, function() {});
}


//below in the background.js file
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.action) {
            case 'closeTab':
                try {
                    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab) {removeTab(tab.id);});
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
);

function removeTab(tabId) {
  try {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId, function() {});
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Your question implies that you have code which you have already tried. In addition, your question does not actually ask a question. You say `window.close()` is very unreliable", but don't say what problem you are having with it (why you consider it unreliable).  You have left this open-ended, effectively asking us to give you code.

Comment: You might want to check out the results of a [Google search for "MDN SDK communicating with page script"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MDN+SDK+communicating+with+page+script).

Comment: I have added my chrome code to the question. window.close() is unreliable, because it does not close windows that are not opened by javascript and may not close always. The content script cannot execute chrome/ff specific functions, so we need to send a message or something to the main.js file in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in content script:

```
self.port.emit("close-tab");
```

in main.js

```
PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: "./content-script.js",
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("close-tab", function() {
      tabs.activeTab.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might help if you are developing an extension of firefox:

```
 function onError(error) {
   console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
 }

 function onRemoved() {
   console.log(`Removed`);    
 }

 function closeTabs(tabIds) {
   removing = browser.tabs.remove(tabIds);
   removing.then(onRemoved, onError); 
 }

 var querying = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true});
 querying.than(closeTabs, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will close the current tab:

```
require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.close();
```

Here's an expanded example that implements a toolbar button that closes the current tab ( silly example, I know ):

```
var ActionButton = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton;
var button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button-id",
  label: "Close this tab",
  icon: {
    "16": "chrome://mozapps/skin/extensions/extensionGeneric.png"
  },
  onClick: function(state) {
    require('sdk/tabs').activeTab.close();
  }
});
```

For more info, please see the [documentation for the tabs module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs).

Comment: Hi. I do know the code, but I need to close the tab from a content script where require("sdk/tabs") is not available. Hence I need to figure out how to send a message to the main.js file, or use some other method to call "require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.close();"